# Loading file from model to spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I want to load my `model` file into `spec`. When i try to `require 'project'` in my spec it does not work. How can i load my model file inside spec.

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/project.rb'

RSpec.describe Project do
  it 'finds an project' do
    project = class_double("project")    
  end
end
```

The above statement tries to load `model` from `spec` directory... but i want to load `model` file which inside app directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
require Rails.root.join("app", "models", "project.rb")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The question was How can i load my model file inside spec and i provided an answer to that!

Comment: It is better, and SO way, to explain why this is the solution and how it works.